# Specify MemoryDependency UWP App

Tags: windows-store-apps, uwp, windows-store

I have a UWP app generated from Unity. I want to limit the availability of my app based on Memory, since it does not run well on less then 1gb. I [found this MemoryDependency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt617330.aspx), but I am not able to apply it in the code of the package.appxmanifest, can somebody tell how this is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right Track. Below are the steps.

> To validate your StoreManifest.xml, create a new xml document in Microsoft Visual Studio and add the following declaration:
>
> `http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2015/StoreManifest` namespace

Below is the StoreManifest.xml for Devices with Min 1 GB

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<StoreManifest xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2015/StoreManifest">
  <Dependencies>
    <MemoryDependency MinForeground="300MB" />
  </Dependencies>
</StoreManifest>
```

Below is the Table for Declaring `MemoryDependency`

> For mobile devices, the value indicates the requirements for available memory. The equivalent requirements for installed memory on mobile devices are as follows:

- 300MB = device must have at least 1 GB of installed memory
- 750MB = device must have at least 2 GB of installed memory
- 1000MB = device must have at least 3 GB of installed memory
- 2000MB = device must have at least 4 GB of installed memory

> For example, if you specify that your UWP app requires 300 MB to run properly, it will only be able to be installed on mobile devices with >1 GB of RAM or on desktop devices with >300 MB of RAM.

More Information and Configuration on how to do this is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/mt617335.aspx)

Comment: I do not seem to have the file, should I create it or make an apppackage?

Comment: @JTIM Yes. You need to create the file. Check the Link in my answer.